# What's the best name for this interface?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an interface that defines the ability to persist an entity to a data store. I'm having trouble thinking of a name for it. Any ideas?

```
public interface IInterfaceForDefiningADataPersistenceOperation<T>
{
    void Store(T entity);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't there also be a retrieval function?

Comment: Normally, yes, although the nature of my application means the data operations are a little different than the norm.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`IRepository` ?

Comment: Indeed - and check out the Repository pattern while you're at it. Good stuff.

Answer (score 8):

How about `IFooRepository`, where `Foo` is some base-entity or describes the product. If it truly is generic, then perhaps just `IRepository<T>`

Answer (score 2):

```
public interface IPersistenceStrategy<T>
```

I'm taking a leap and saying you're using the [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) in order to persist things in different ways depending on the strategy you provide.

Answer (score 1):

Did you not like any of these?

- IPersistenceOperation
- IDataStoreOperation
- IEntityStoreOperation

Answer (score 1):

IPersistEntities

Then you can derive class MyNewPersistenceThing : IPersistEntities

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for IStorable

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't an interface be defining a group of operations, rather than 'an operation'?

Answer (score 0):

IGateway

Then implementations are (for example):
UserGateway, ArticleGateway and so on

Answer (score 0):

If your interface follows the [repository pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) then I would go with IRepository.

If not then perhaps [IDataMapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) is more suitable.